# Pandas Create DataFrame with ColumnNames from a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Considering the following list made up of sub-lists as elements, I need to create a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
```

The desired output is as following, with the first argument being converted to the column name in the dataframe.

```
   tom  nick  juli
0   10    15    14
```

Is there a way by which this output can be achieved?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print ({x[0]: x[1:] for x in data})
{'tom': [10], 'nick': [15], 'juli': [14]}

df = pd.DataFrame({x[0]: x[1:] for x in data})
print (df)
   tom  nick  juli
0   10    15    14
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael this works exactly as needed. You've helped me out here again, can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) + [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]

result = pd.DataFrame(dict((column, values) for column, *values in data))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   tom  nick  juli
0   10    15    14
```

Answer (score 2):

We also do:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(0).T
```

---

```
0  tom  nick  juli
1   10    15    14
```

Comment: Thanks @ansev This is also a solution !